'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. typescript
How to solve the error for numbers when it should  be string here is the code
<FlipNumbers 
                height={12} 
                width={12} 
                color="white" 
                background="red" 
                play perspective={100} 
                numbers={visitor?.count} />;


From NPM, numbers only accept string value. You are providing the value with number | undefined type

Well, it looks numbers is expecting a string. Without knowing what's inside the FlipNumbers component, or what visitor?.count is expected to be, there's no way for us to know what/where the fix should be.

Seems like the prop numbers is expecting a string, and not a number | undefined type. The value of visitors?.count will either be undefined or a number, so there's a type mismatch.
There are two ways you can resolve this issue:

If you control the component FlipNumbers - you can change its prop type to accept number | undefined.
If you don't want to change the component, you can just convert the number to a string. This will also require you to provide a default number / value in case the value is undefined. For example, if you want to default to 0, it'll look like: numbers={`${visitor?.count ?? 0}`}

